# Log.d(String, String) crashes my program?

Tags: android, debugging, logging

if I add this code to any of my methods to check for fragment being null or not; my program crashes. But if I comment out the Log.d(), the program does not crash?

What could be wrong here?

```
if(cyclefragment.equals(null)){
        Log.d("TESTING CYCLEFRAG NULL", "CycleFrag is null");
        }else{
            Log.d("TESTING CYCLEFRAG NULL", "CycleFrag is not null");
        }
        if(cyclefragment.a1.equals(null)){
            Log.d("TESTING A1 NULL", "A1 is null");
        }else{
            Log.d("TESTING A1 NULL", "A1 is not null");
        }
```

**LogCat:**

```
 03-24 03:37:27.461: E/Trace(13979): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nanospark.upcdemo/com.nanospark.upcdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at com.nanospark.upcdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:75)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
03-24 03:37:27.928: E/AndroidRuntime(13979):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: i guess its the if condition that actually causes the crash not the log d may be..

Comment: Then how would it work if I only comment out the log.d and none of the conditions?

Comment: if(cyclefragment.a1.equals(null)){

Comment: I figured out my problem; I never instantiated the field a1 in the cyclefragment class.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to hammer me with downvotes guys. It was an honest mistake.

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your post. Answers become useless without a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

if condition that actually causes the problem not the `log.d()`

```
    if(cyclefragment == null){
        Log.d("TESTING CYCLEFRAG NULL", "CycleFrag is null");
    }else{
        Log.d("TESTING CYCLEFRAG NULL", "CycleFrag is not null");
    }
    if(cyclefragment.a1 == null){
        Log.d("TESTING A1 NULL", "A1 is null");
    }else{
        Log.d("TESTING A1 NULL", "A1 is not null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem; I never instantiated the field a1 in the cyclefragment class. Sorry guys.

Comment: told you its the if with the problem!